# Usage of a PC as a SD Card with adapter

Tags: computer-hardware, camera-controls

I am searching for something like a SD card with a second conectorto USB, so I can put the card into my Cam and plug the usb into my PC, so that I'm able to shoot some pictures directly to my HD (in PC).

Before you ask: my cam isn't able to do this per usb, so I want the camera to "think" it has an SD card, but it is directly connected to my PC.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst not a direct USB link, there is a product called an [eye-fi](http://uk.eye.fi/how-it-works/basics) which allows your camera to send your photos directly to you computer, when it is within range of specified wireless networks. The 4Gb version retails around the £50 mark on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B003E47XIQ/)

Comment: Well, this is great even better than my usb suggestion, because of beeing wireless